# Which is the correct way to handle values props before charge component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

i have a doubt about React hook, his props and useEffect.

In my component, i receive a list inside props, i must filter the received list and get a value from the list before the component is mounted.

**(this code is a simplified example, i apply another filters and conditions more complex)**

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null)

  useEffect(()=>{
    var found = props.myList.find((x)=> {return x.name=="TEST"});

    if(found.length > 0)
        setValue("Hello World")
  }, []);

  return (
   <div>{value}</div>
  )
}
```

**Is correct to use useEffect for get and set a value respect to props before the component is mounted?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `useEffect` is executed after the 1st render, so `null` would be "rendered" first, and then the `useEffect` would update the state causing another render.

However, if your value is dependent on the props, and maybe on other states (filters for example), this is a derived value, and it doesn't need to be used as a state. Instead calculate it on each render, and if it's a heavy computation that won't change on every render wrap it with `useMemo`:

```
function MyComponent({ myList }) {
  const value = useMemo(() => {
    const found = myList.some(x => x.name=="TEST");
  
    return found ? 'Hello World' : '';
  }, [myList]);

  return (
   <div>{value}</div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use `useEffect` here, you can simply pass a callback to the `useState` hook. The callback is only ran on the initialization of the hook so this has the same outcome as your `useEffect` hook (i.e. it doesn't run on every rerender so same performance hit).

```
function MyComponent({ myList }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    const found = myList.find(x => x.name === 'TEST');

    return found ? 'Hello World' : null;
  });

  return (
    <div>{value}</div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for any hook at all, actually, you should just write it like this:

```js
function MyComponent({ myList }) {
  const found = myList.some(x => x.name == "TEST");
  const value = found ? 'Hello World' : '';

  return (
   <div>{value}</div>
  )
}
```

Using `useEffect` or even only `useState` is conceptually wrong. The `useState` hook is used when a component needs to have its own independent internal state which isn't the case here, as the value is purely derived from the props. The `useEffect` hook is an escape hatch typically used when you need to sync with some external imperative API, not at all the case here.

The solution with `useMemo` is perfectly fine, and more efficient if your filtering condition is very computationally expensive, but it is also a lot more complicated to understand and to maintain, so I would suggest going for the simplest solution until the lack of memoization actually becomes a measurable problem.